# Getting search result on different form in a grid in window Application

Tags: .net

i am using window forms application.I Wants when i click on Search button,new form must be open containing the Result of Search and when i select a record it must be inserted into corresponding Textboxes. Please suggest me sir.

Answer (score 0):

This web site has a good example of how to do this.

http://net-informations.com/q/faq/passvalues.html

```
private void seachbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 resultform = new Form2(object);
  resultform.show();
}
```

Jim